# Multiline Ellipsis Error in IE8 jquery

Tags: jquery

My little multiline ellipsis jquery (...) doesn't want to work in IE8 as is. It works great in IE9, Firefox, Chrome. I need assistance solving this problem for the IE8.

I created a jsfiddle to give you a demo if you would help me out: http://jsfiddle.net/9GSWY/

```
var myTag = $('.description').text();
if (myTag.length > 100) {
var truncated = myTag.trim().substring(0, 100).split(" ").slice(0, -1).join(" ") + "...";
$('.description').text(truncated); // truncate multiline blog viewlet with ellipsis 
}
```

Using IE8, it returns this error "Option doesn't support this property or method" and it points to this line:

```
var truncated = myTag.trim().substring(0, 100).split(" ").slice(0, -1).join(" ") + "...";
```

**JSFIDDLE**
http://jsfiddle.net/9GSWY/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String.prototype.trim` isn't supported in IE8, instead try using jQuery's built-in trim:

```
$.trim(myTag).substring(0, 100).split(" ").slice(0, -1).join(" ") + "..."
```

Answer (score 2):

I get `Object doesn't support property or method 'trim'` in IE8, without `.trim()` works fine.